# NAV tag content does not work after replacing INNERHTML

Tags: javascript, css, innerhtml, nav

I have an existing NAV tag that contains UL list items.  The original HTML works when the NAV tag contents are left as is.  When I replace the INNERHTML with my own HTML, which resembles the original HTML AS-IS, word for word, the NAV will not DROP-DOWN like the original does any longer.  I've checked every letter and word.  I did notice that one of the ANCHOR HREF does contain #.  Here is what's in the original NAV.

```
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
<li class="current"><a href="index.html">Welcome</a></li>
<li class="submenu">
<a href="#">Show Me</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="hybrid/index.html">The Hybrid</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

My code appears as such

---

```
var pstrHTML = "<ul>"
+ "<li class='current'><a href='index.html'>Welcome</a></li>"
+ "<li class='submenu'>"
+ "<a href='#'>Show Me</a>"
+ "<ul>"
+ "<li><a href='hybrid/index.html'>The Hybrid</a></li>"
+ "</ul>"
+ "</li>"
+ "</ul>";
document.getElementById("nav").innerHTML = pstrHTML;
```

---

If I stick an ONCLICK containing a WINDOW.ALERT on the SHOW ME list item, it does generate an ALERT when clicked.  So I know the INNERHTML is working via the ONPAGELOAD.  But for whatever reason, the NAV won't work to match the original HTML.

Comment: You've attached event listeners to the original elements, and `innerHTML` creates new elements to show. Though those new elements look same, they're not the same elements than the originals having the events attached. If you can't manipulate the content with `append` / `appendChild` / `insertBefore` / `insertAdjacentElement` / `insertAdjacentHTML` methods, then you've to delegate the events on an ancestor element (on `nav`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deleting the element, the event bound to it will be deleted as well.

To make the event persistent, you could bind the event to the document instead of the element with `document.AddEventListener()`. Then we need to check the target if it has the id `#ShowMe`.

```
document.AddEventListener("click",function(e) {
   if(e.target = "#idOfYourElement"){
      // do something
   }
});
```

Run working demo below;

```js
document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target = "#ShowMe") {
    alert("Hello World!");
    var pstrHTML = "<ul>" +
      "<li class='current'><a href='index.html'>Welcome</a></li>" +
      "<li class='submenu'>" +
      "<a id='ShowMe' href='#'>Show Me</a>" +
      "<ul>" +
      "<li><a href='hybrid/index.html'>The Hybrid</a></li>" +
      "<li><a href='hybrid/index.html'>New Element 1</a></li>" +
      "<li><a href='hybrid/index.html'>New Element 2</a></li>" +
      "</ul>" +
      "</li>" +
      "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("nav").innerHTML = pstrHTML;
  }
});
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Welcome</a></li>
    <li class="submenu">
      <a id="ShowMe" href="#">Show Me</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="hybrid/index.html">The Hybrid</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

`document.AddEventListener()` is equivalent to `$(document).on("action","#id",function(){ });` in jquery.

EDIT: Included Teemu's answer, this will work as well;

```
document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target = "#ShowMe") {
     // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be `document`, any common ancestor will do, the closer the better.

Comment: So, I did something rather stupid and simple.  This is a very simple site.  For whatever reason, if the NAV object on HTML5 gets touched after the page is loaded, the NAV object fails.  Therefore, I wrote a simple VBA application in MS ACCESS, opened each page on the site recorded into a LIST/TABLE and then modified the entire NAV section using a HTML model that is standard across all pages.   I burned so many hours trying various JSCRIPT code and just resolved to VBA to update the NAV pre-deployment.  Thanks for all the help.